# vendure-auth-token in next js

Tags: authentication, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

As I am using vendure graphql in my next js project and I am using apolloClient for query and mutation , I am facing an problem after login mutation

My client code

```
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";

import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

const { BACKEND_URL } = process.env;

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: BACKEND_URL as string,
      credentials: "include",
    }),
  });
});
```

My login code

```
const apolloClient = getClient();
```

```
export const login = async ({
  username,
  password,
  rememberMe,
}: MutationLoginArgs) => {
  const response = await apolloClient.mutate<LoginMutation>({
    mutation: Login,
    variables: {
      rememberMe: rememberMe ? true : false,
      username,
      password,
    },
  });
  return response;
};
```

I am getting vendure-auth-token in graphql playground network >> response >> headers.

How to get this vendure-auth-token in code for further authorize query and mutation